# Add Items to the ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have a **ComboBox** control.

I bind to this control to the DataSet table.

Here is the code:

```
comboBox.Items.Add(("Select"));
comboBox.DataSource = DataSet.ColorTable;
comboBox.DisplayMember = DataSet.ColorTable.ColorNameColumn.ColumnName;
comboBox.ValueMember = DataSet.ColorTable.ColorIDColumn.ColumnName;
```

This result I get:

[image]

I want to display on the top of the list **SELECT:** word. So I need to add addition Item to the comboBox control. 
Here how I implement it:

```
cmbCategory.Items.Add(("Select"));
```

But the result is still the same as above. I get only colors without **SELECT:** word on the top of the list.

Any idea how I can add this string-**SELECT:** to the ComboBox control and set to this string `ValueMember`?

Comment: You can't mix `Items` and `DataSource`.

Comment: Windows forms? ASP.Net? WPF?

Comment: Add "Select" to the `ColorTable`

Comment: Appears to be two different ComboBox: cmbCategory comboBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the collections of color to an `array` or a `dataset` (if you are getting them from database) first and then add items "select", then add each elements of the array or a column of the `dataset`.

Do this in `Form_Load` function and wherever there are changes made in color collections array or database.

Answer (score 8):

Use `Insert` method instead.

```
cmbCategory.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
```

**Note :** Put this code after the databind.

Comment: No, you would get `System.ArgumentException`. The DataSource must be consistent with the Items, you can't mix them. Also, generally is a bad idea to use an item to instruct the user to select one other item in the combobox. The OP should include a separate label or text to instruct the user that the selection is mandatory and leave the combobox items clean.

Comment: This is not a valid answer anymore

Comment: @ChangeWorld, may you please share the updated one? As I'm seeing the document the insert method is still present with the "Item" property as its a type of "ObjectCollection". 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.items?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan when I try to insert after the databind I get the following error: `System.ArgumentException: Cannot modify the collection of elements when the DataSource property is set`, but I'm still searching for the right answer on the net. Just wanned to let you know that is throwing an error

Answer (score 2):

```
            //This will set Display member and value member
            comboBox.DisplayMember = "ColorName";
            comboBox.ValueMember = "ColorCode";

          //This will add a new row to table in binded dataset
            DataRow dr = dal.MyProperty_dsColors.Tables["ColorInfo"].NewRow();
            dr["ColorName"] = "Select Color"; //SomeName
            dr["ColorCode"] = 001; //Some ID
            dal.MyProperty_dsColors.Tables["ColorInfo].Rows.Add(dr); 

           //binding dataSource
            comboBox.DataSource = dal.MyProperty_dsColors.Tables["ColorInfo"];
```

Answer (score 1):

What would also help you is that you set the ComboBox without having to 'Select' it when the popup arrives...
Select your ComboBox, under the properties tab, select Appearance->Drop Down Style and select DropDownList.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to add manually values in a `combobox` (for example `integers`) this can be done using a for loop:

```
// sample code
int lower=1;
int higher=500;

for (int i=lower; i<=higher; i++)
 combo_values.Items.Add(i.ToString());
```

Note that you have to use the `int.Parse(combo_values.Text)` command to read a value.