# C# Combobox hardcoding values

Tags: c#, combobox, hardcode, hardcoded

So I have a combo box called `cboGender`, I want to add values (hard code the values) to the combo box like `Male`, `Female` and `Unspecified`. How do I go about doing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little bit of research would give you the answer to your question. [Read This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143287/add-items-to-the-combobox).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the items by clicking the combo box's item collection editor and enter the items line by line.

[image: Items Collection editor]

Answer (score 0):

cboGender.Items.Add(new Item("Male"));

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple ways of how you can populate `comboBox`, you can either add items one by one or you can add a whole collection etc...
Adding items one by one could be done like this:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("Male");
comboBox1.Items.Add("Female");
comboBox1.Items.Add("Unspecified");
```

Adding the same above items in a single statement could be done like this:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[]{ "Male","Female","Unspecified"});
```

You can set a List of class objects as a datasource to your `comboBox` as well. Create a class like this:

```
class personGender
{
  public string gender { get; set; }
}
```

Set the datasource of `comboBox` like this:

```
List<personGender> list = new List<personGender>()
{
 new personGender{gender="Male"},
 new personGender{gender="Female"},
 new personGender{gender="Unspecified"},
};
comboBox1.DataSource = list;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "gender";
```

Or you can do the same above this within 2 lines like this:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = new List<personGender>()
{
 new personGender{gender="Male"},
 new personGender{gender="Female"},
 new personGender{gender="Unspecified"},
};
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "gender";
```

You can also set its `datasource` after fetching the records from your database.

Hope it helps!